# Difference in outcome when Node code is in function vs. out of function

Tags: node.js

Okay, so I have what is effectively two identical (to my eyes at least!) pieces of Node JS code. The only difference is that in once case it is wrapped up in a function and called via that function and in the other case, the code sits outside any function. When I run the two pieces, of what should be identical code, I get vastly different results. Why is this?

Here is the code when not inside of a function:

```
chunks = []
req = https.get('https://www.example.com',
                res => {
                    res.setEncoding('utf8')
                    res.on('data', chunk => {
                        chunks.push(chunk)
                    })
                    res.on('end', function(){
                        chunks.join()
                    })
                }).end()
console.log(chunks[0])
```

Here is me using what, as far as I can tell, should effectively be the exact same code but via a function format:

```
function readURI(uri){
    const chunks = []
    const req = https.get(uri, res => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8')
        res.on('data', chunk => {
            chunks.push(chunk)
        })
        res.on('end', function(){
            chunks.join()
        })
    })
    req.end()
    return chunks[0]
}
console.log(readURI('https://www.example.com'))
```

I run both of these in the Node REPL. In the first instance, `chunks[0]` is a string with the content of the website as I expect. In the second, I get no data in the return of the function. Why would this happen?

Comment: I get `undefined` with both.

Comment: Can you post the complete function in the first case? Maybe just post the complete program/script.

Comment: @GandalfTheGrey I'm not sure what you mean? There is no function in the first case. In the first the call to `console.log(chunks[0])` is printing out the HTML as expected. In the second, I get `undefined`. In the first case, there is no function and that's what has led me to this question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance how are you running the snippets? I'm running them from the Node REPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple mistake in interacting with the REPL. In entering the code into the REPL, I did so without a new line on the last line of code and so the request object has been made and completed by the time I hit enter on the final `console.log` line. In the case of the function based snippet, this doesn't matter as the request is made in the same line and doesn't have time to complete by the time the log is made.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things at play here.

- When a line is evaluated, the completion value of the line is displayed when using the Node REPL - even if the line doesn't include a `console.log`. As a result, the first code's `req = https.get('https://www.example.com',` logs the request object.
- Look at what gets logged carefully - it really does not contain the content of the website anywhere - the request is asynchronous, it has not finished by the time the final line is executed.

```
Welcome to Node.js v14.17.6.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const https = require('https');
undefined
> chunks = []
[]
> req = https.get('https://www.example.com',
...                 res => {
.....                     res.setEncoding('utf8')
.....                     res.on('data', chunk => {
.......                         chunks.push(chunk)
.......                     })
.....                     res.on('end', function(){
.......                         chunks.join()
.......                     })
.....                 }).end()
ClientRequest {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    response: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function (anonymous)] }
  },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [
    {
      data: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
      encoding: 'latin1',
      callback: [Function: bound onFinish]
    }
  ],
  outputSize: 60,
  writable: true,
  destroyed: false,
  _last: true,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  _defaultKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 0,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  socket: null,
  _header: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
  _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
  _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
  agent: Agent {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      free: [Function (anonymous)],
      newListener: [Function: maybeEnableKeylog]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    defaultPort: 443,
>
    options: { path: null },
    requests: {},
    sockets: { 'www.example.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::': [Array] },
    freeSockets: {},
    keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
    keepAlive: false,
    maxSockets: Infinity,
    maxFreeSockets: 256,
    scheduling: 'lifo',
    maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
    totalSocketCount: 1,
    maxCachedSessions: 100,
    _sessionCache: { map: {}, list: [] },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  socketPath: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  maxHeaderSize: undefined,
  insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
  path: '/',
  _ended: false,
  res: null,
  aborted: false,
  timeoutCb: null,
  upgradeOrConnect: false,
  parser: null,
  maxHeadersCount: null,
  reusedSocket: false,
  host: 'www.example.com',
  protocol: 'https:',
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] { host: [ 'Host', 'www.example.com' ] }
}
> console.log(chunks[0])
undefined
undefined
>
```

The website content is not in there - in either version of your code, as expected. It's just that your first code has the request as a completion value of a line, but the second code does not - and in the function version, `chunks` is an empty array when `readURI` finishes, so `undefined` is returned.

Unless you're sure you know exactly how the REPL works, to avoid confusing yourself, I'd recommend running scripts as their own files - eg `node example.js` - for anything that isn't exceedingly trivial.

Comment: Great answer. Who knows what could be going on there...

Comment: I think a good approach to answering a question is to assume the premise. For example, in this case, I'm not talking at all about the request object being printed. I'm specifically talking about the chunks object being printed with exactly what I expect. What seems to actually be causing this is that I am pasting the snippet in without a new line and then when I hit enter again on the final line, the request has already completed.